# Django-CMS: How do I get a parent item of a currently active child page to highlight in the navigation menu?

Tags: django-cms

The standard menu.html that comes with Django CMS seems really easy but I simply can't figure out how to highlight a menu item that has children that are currently active.

I tried this:

```
{% if child.children and child.selected %} active dropdown{% endif %}
```

But that, for some odd reason, doesn't work.

Below is the full code of the menu.html:

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}

{% for child in children %}
    <li class="{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}
        {% if child.selected %} active{% endif %}
        {% if child.children %} dropdown{% endif %}
 --->   {% if child.selected and child.children %} active dropdown{% endif %}">
        {% if child.children %}
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                {{ child.get_menu_title }} <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}"><span>{{ child.get_menu_title }}</span></a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% if class and forloop.last and not forloop.parentloop %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Koistinen of Divio, I got a working solution:

Template tag and its config:

```
{% show_menu 0 1 0 0 "menu.html" %}
```

Menu.html:

```
{% load i18n menu_tags cache %}

{% for child in children %}
<li class="{% if child.ancestor %}ancestor{% endif %}{% if child.selected %} active{% endif %}">
    <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```